# listing out arrays with different number of elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The way the models are associated in my Rails app, if I try to list the licenses that a user has with code like this

```
Licensed in <%= answer.user.licenses.map(&:state) %>
```

it'll print out like this

```
Licensed in ["New York"]
```

Since it's an array, I can remove the array brackets like this

```
<%= answer.user.licenses.map(&:state)[0] %>
```

and I get the result I want

```
Licensed in New York
```

However, if a user has more than one license (which is a possibility), that's not a good solution, as each license should be listed.

Therefore, I tried this

```
   <% answer.user.licenses.map(&:state).each do |state| %>
    <%= state %>
   <% end %>
```

However, this won't add "smart" commas between licenses, smart meaning "add a comment where necessary but not at the end."

What should the code look like to achieve what I'm trying to do in this situation. I wasn't sure of the keywords I should google to figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails, you can use `to_sentence`.  That will place a `,` between all of the elements and will place the word `and` between the penultimate and ultimate words.

Comment: That's amazing how I learn new stuff with rails everyday, great method !

Comment: ActiveSupport core extensions is full of all kinds of goodies that make life easier.  You can find a bunch of them at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html.

Comment: My favorite would be the date extensions such as ``2.hours.from_now``, awesome.

Comment: Woefully off-topic, but check out the Chronic gem.  It allows you to perform calculations using natural language.  For example, `Chronic.parse('next thursday')` will provide a datetime of next Thursday.  It's pretty slick.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
answer.user.licenses.map(&:state).join(',')
```

This will add `,` between each element of the array.